# Bootstrap Navbar not readable on small screen

Tags: bootstrap-4

My bootstraps navbar is not visible on a small screen, can somebody help me with it? on wide screen its working fine!

```
<main class="container border rounded mt-3">
<div class="row">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-info col-lg-12">
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item <c:if test="${param.page =='index' }">active</c:if>">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="index.htm">Home </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item <c:if test="${param.page =='wagens' }">active</c:if>">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="<c:url value="/wagens/list.htm"/>">Wagens</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item <c:if test="${param.page =='wasbeurt' }">active</c:if>">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="<c:url value="/wagens/wasbeurt.htm"/>">Wasbeurt</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item <c:if test="${param.page =='admin' }">active</c:if>">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="<c:url value="/wagens/new.htm"/>">Admin</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <span class="navbar-text">
                24/06/2018 17:41
            </span>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

[navbar on small screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21h20.png)

Answer (score 0):

Read the Navbar docs: http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/navbar/#supported-content

1. All the Navbar content is inside the `collapse` which hides on lg and under since navbar-expand-lg is used
2. If you're going to use Navbar collapse you should have a toggler button

***Or***, don't use collapse and keep the navbar expanded on all breakpoints (`navbar-expand`)

https://www.codeply.com/go/3uTvc5EtTh